# Added payment status doesn't appear on bulk edit in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I added new payment status (reminded_second & reminded_third) according to the guideline:
https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/tutorials-and-faq/create-new-order-and-payment-status

So far so good, it works when I'm editing a single order, but when I try to bulk edit orders, the new payment status doesn't appear.

Anyone can tell me, how I can make it visible there as well? Do i need to do something else?

Comment: A possible reason could be that the payment do not have a state from which can be transitioned into the state reminded_second or reminded_third. What happens if you only bulk-edit the one order that has the new payment states as possible selection?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is, that I'm testing it with just one order which I can assign on the single mode but not on the bulk mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marcus already mentioned, Shopware features a transition system for states. Within that system, states may be limited in the way they may be transitioned to or from.

Let's say there are 3 hypothetical states: `x`, `y`, `z`

- If you're on state `x`, you may transition to state `y` but not `z`
- If you're on state `y`, you may transition to state `z` but not `x`
- If you're on state `z`, you may transition to state `x` but not `y`

There's an [in depth part of the documentation](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/tutorials-and-faq/create-new-order-and-payment-status#workflow-transition) on how you can set up your state and in which ways it may be transitioned to.

Within the bulk edit the current states of the selected orders may differ. Thus not all included orders may be compliant with a transition to a specific state. Hence why in the bulk edit you'll only be able to select a state to transition to, which satisfies the transition constraints of all orders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as i already mentioned, i did it already according this guideline. And it works on a single order but if i try to bulk edit with only one and the same order, where i should have the same options, i do not have the status available. There is nothing about that in the documentation. So what could be the issue here then?